# Restore SharePoint Profile Picture from Content DB backup?

Tags: 2013, mysites

I have a backup of the MySites Content DB. Is it possible to restore a shp profile picture from it? As well as the "About Me" information by chance?

Answer (score 2):

"About Me" is held within the UPSA Profile database. If your CDB contains the MySite Host there will be a User Photos library at the root of the site where you can grab the pictures from.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor! I will try to restore the referenced CDB in dev and see if it can be recovered.

Comment: Hi Trevor, when trying to recover the "About Me" info from the UPSA Pro DB - I'm getting a "There is a compatibility range mismatch between the web server..." error. 
Is there an alternative way of going about this?
Thanks so much!